# The integrals of two continuous functions $f,g:[-\pi ,\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ multiplied with $e^{inx}$ are equal. But is $f=g$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, derivatives, continuity

I have two continuous functions $f,g$, that have equal integrals from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ when multiplied with $e^{inx}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

$e^{inx}$ is always continuous, so both $f(x)e^{inx}$ and $g(x)e^{inx}$. Does it hold to say that the derivatives of the integrals of these must be equal, thus $f(x)e^{inx}=g(x)e^{inx}$, which gives us that $f=g$?

Comment: Do you know about Fourier transforms ?

Comment: Yes, so since the integrals are equal Fourier transforms of a function h, then the functions f and g themselves must be equal?

Comment: Recall that $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^\pi_{-\pi}|f|^2=\sum_{n}|c_n|^2$ where $c_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}f(t)e^{-in t}\,dt$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. What can you say about $\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}|f-g|^2$ ?

Comment: Well, i guess $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f-g|=0$, thus we need to have $f-g=0$

Comment: @Samsam22: wel yes, $\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}|f-g|\leq \sqrt{2\pi}\Big(\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}|f-g|^2\Big)$. Either of those integrals will work. Since your functions are continuous, there is no remedy but to conclude that $f=g$ (why?)